# Select distinct on Left Join for only one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to list products that each customer bought, but if they bought the same item on different occasions, I want it to exclude it.  This is what I have so far:

```
Select  c.field_id_33  AS email, o.order_id, Group_concat(o.entry_id) AS Products,group_concat(t.title),group_concat(t.url_title) from finn_cartthrob_order_items o  
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_data c
ON c.entry_id=o.order_id
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles t
ON o.entry_id=t.entry_id
GROUP BY email
```

This is producing:

[image: screenshot]

Basically I only need a product listed one time if they've purchased it, no matter how many times they've purchased it.  How would I do this?

Comment: What do you want your result to look like? Also, best practice is to GROUP BY every column in the SELECT clause that does not involve an aggregate function.

Comment: How come your screen shot is missing the email column and the others?

Comment: Because the database is full and I don't feel like photoshopping out a bunch of email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` in group_concat function,using [Group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) baware of that fact it has a default limit of 1024 characters to group them but it can be increased

```
Select  c.field_id_33  AS email, o.order_id, 
Group_concat(DISTINCT o.entry_id) AS Products,
group_concat(DISTINCT t.title),
group_concat(DISTINCT t.url_title)
 from finn_cartthrob_order_items o  
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_data c
ON c.entry_id=o.order_id
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles t
ON o.entry_id=t.entry_id
GROUP BY email
```

> From the docs The result is truncated to the maximum length that is
>   given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default
>   value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective
>   maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of
>   group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an
>   unsigned integer:
>
> SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could use distinct inside group_concat

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can use `distinct` after the `select` keyword, you can also use it inside aggregate functions (including `group_concat`), to aggregate each distinct value only once:

```
Select  
  c.field_id_33  AS email, o.order_id, 
  Group_concat(DISTINCT o.entry_id) AS Products,
  group_concat(DISTINCT t.title),
  group_concat(DISTINCT t.url_title) 
from finn_cartthrob_order_items o  
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_data c
ON c.entry_id=o.order_id
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles t
ON o.entry_id=t.entry_id
GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using ROW_NUMBER over PARTITION BY?

Here is a sample.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT order_id, 
          entry_id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY entry_id
              ORDER BY entry_id) AS ProductCount
           FROM finn_cartthrob_order_items
            ) AS Products
WHERE   ProductCount = 1
ORDER BY Products.order_id
```

This should return the first order_id and entry_id for each entry_id. It functions conceptually similar to this.

```
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM finn_cartthrob_order_items
    WHERE entry_id = @Specific_entry_id
```

You might need to include some of your left joins inside the Over(Partition By).